# Django user registration without username

Tags: python, django

I am making django registration form

At first this code works well

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username","email", "password1", "password2"]

def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("/login")
```

However now I want to make email as username, so my idea is like this

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["email", "password1", "password2"] #delete username from home.

def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        if not response.POST._mutable:
            response.POST._mutable = True
        response.POST['username'] = random.randrange(1000000) # force change username
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

However after this username is not registered.

What is wrong??

Comment: Could it be that you're setting username to an integer instead of a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However after this username is not registered.

It is not registered, since the form does not contain a field named `username`, and thus the form will ignore this.

You can set a username with:

```
form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.username = f'{random.randrange(10000000)}'
    form.save()
```

That being said, it might be better to [*implement a custom user model*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model), and set `email` as the `USERNAME_FIELD`. In that case your user model, does not have a `username` field.

Comment: this will not work for 2 same randrange results

Comment: @OceanFire: correct, although this is unlikely. This is the birthday problem but with a much larger denominator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem just like using a GUUID ultimately also has a chance of a clash: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions as discussed the main problem is using the old username without a username. In that case working with a user model without a username and usnique email address is better.